# Some images don't get linked when setting link-to to media-image

Tags: images, media-library

When inserting images into posts I have some images which refuse to recognize their link-to setting. The setting is properly saved and I also tried switching to a none setting and back, but with no effect. This only occurs for some images, regardless of the other settings and the context where it is inserted. Any clues what my cause this?

**EDIT:** By some images I mean just random images. There are Jpegs (there might be some png, but this seems not to be related) like the others which work with description or without. They are all uploaded from the media library or directly from the post. Re-uploading seems to fix the issue, but it reoccurs from time to time with new images.

To make this issue even more weird: It works when I remove the description-text for those images, but when I add it again (or a single letter for testing purposes), it does not work anymore.

**EDIT 2:** 
Also cropping, flipping or other file-modifications don't affect the described behavior for those images.

**EDIT 3:** Probably because of using the custom-upload-dir-extension some of my guids seem to be messed up and some of those files are the ones which are problematic.

**EDIT 4:** Even with removing the custom-upload-dir-extension the problem still occurs, for new and old images...

Comment: When you say "some images", which ones are you refering to. Is it just certain extentions you are refering to? If so, please edit your question and add that relevant info to the question

Comment: Is it specific to image? Does it always [not] happen if you are uploading same image file?

Comment: @Rarst it is specific to images and as described it does not happen necessarily for the same file, when uploading again.